# How to make a website world wide accessible by python script or anything else(without any help of DNS and online servers)?

Tags: python, server, dns, web-hosting

I am new to web developing so just for the learning purpose I made a website which is on my laptop and I want to access it through other device(which is not in the same network) Since I know the IP of my laptop and I am the only one person trying to access it so I don't need any DNS(i.e godaddy) and big online server(i.e AWS) So how can I do it with the help of python or anything which is already on my laptop.The aim of doing this is to learn how to make website online without any help of software and DNS just for the personal use or for a small group.It will be helpful if you keep explanation of networking part simple  and Thanks

Comment: Do you have a static IP address? In most consumer contracts, you IP changes regularly. If you don't want to use something like dynDNS, you will have to manually check it quite often.

Comment: Something like ngrok.io just for testing.

Comment: Look to your internet provider with keywords like `domain` `reverse DNS`

Comment: I just have seen how to set static IP. Now what should I fill in DNS server blank and what next after setting static IP?@Sebastian E